# Giving a border to Canvas

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, border

In Flex, I am using

```
var canvasEdit:Canvas = new Canvas();
canvasEdit.setStyle("borderColor", 0x0134FF);
canvasEdit.setStyle("borderThickness", 3);
```

But I am not able to put border on the sides of the Canvas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following line:

```
canvasEdit.setStyle("borderStyle","solid");
```

...for example, here is a full application file example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            protected function init():void
            {
                canvasEdit.setStyle("borderStyle","solid");
                canvasEdit.setStyle("borderColor","#000000");
                canvasEdit.setStyle("borderThickness","5");
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Canvas width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0" id="canvasEdit"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: please could you help me if i would use a group in Flex 4.5 which canvas is obsolete, how can i define the `borderStyle`, `borderColor` and `themeColor`