# Custom flex mx Canvas borderThickness doesn't work

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, coding-style

```
package custom
{
    import mx.containers.Canvas;

    public class CustomCanvas extends Canvas
    {
        public function CustomCanvas()
        {
            super();
        }
        override protected function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties();

            this.setStyle('backgroundColor',0x0055ff);
            this.setStyle('borderColor',0x00aaff);
            this.setStyle('borderThickness',5);
            this.setStyle('borderStyle',"solid");
        }
    }
}
```

The style borderThickness doesn't apply. What Iwrong with canvas style initialization?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338957/in-flex-giving-border-to-canvas) to address your issue.  You need quotes surrounding the "5" for your border thickness:

```
canvasEdit.setStyle("borderThickness","5");
```