# Flex: How to set border-width?

Tags: apache-flex

In Flex 4, I have a canvas that I'd like to set border-width on via css. I can set the border color and border style, but the border width remains 1 pixel wide no matter what.

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Style source="global.css" />

<mx:Canvas id="login_panel" width="300" height="200">
    <s:Label text="hi there"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

global.css:

```
#login_panel {
border-weight:5px;
border-color:#00ff00;
border-style:solid;
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a BorderContainer there?  It looks like borderThickness is not a supported style for Canvas if you are using the Spark theme.

Comment: Looks like this is going to be the way to go. Thanks for your help Amy. Much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338957/in-flex-giving-border-to-canvas

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `border-thickness:5;` ?

Comment: I get the same result when using border-thickness:5; Thanks for the suggestion tho...

Comment: @steven did you try with `border-thickness:5px;` too?

Comment: Yep. If i use border-thickness:5px; I get no border at all.

Comment: @steven Ah, well. Was just a guess. I haven't had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your css is wrong.  `id="login_panel"` should be `styleName="login_panel"` in your mxml.  Then in your css `#login_panel` should be `.login_panel`.

Aside from that, you are using Flex 4 so you should use [BorderContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/BorderContainer.html) not Canvas.

Comment: Flex 4 CSS rules - Identifiers :: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_use_the_new_CSS_syntax_in_Flex_4-15726.html

Comment: I don't think I deserve a down vote on this.  Both syntaxes are valid, See "Global Selection" in your link.

Comment: Both syntaxes are valid, but **you told OP that his was wrong.**

Comment: Fair enough.  Then you should have said that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the CSS property **border-width**?

Check out this web page for more info:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp